# Hotel search engine that sorts results by distance from a given address by public transit?

Tags: online-resources, hotels, accommodation-search-engines

When I'm traveling to a city with good public transport, I often prefer to save money by booking a place that is well connected to the city center by bus/tram/metro instead of a hotel that's directly downtown. However the most popular search engines fail to properly address this use case and I'm forced to sift through the search results looking up the distance from downtown to the hotel on Google Maps.

Is there a website that better caters to this need by letting you sort hotels by distance on public transport?

Comment: The hotels themselves won't tell you the truth because they want you to book. "10 minutes walk from the city centre" can mean "10 minutes fast walk for an athlete to the nearest edge of the official city boundary."

Comment: @WeatherVane Or they just define "downtown" as including areas that aren't; I was in a "downtown" hotel in Madison, US-WI and it was only "downtown" in comparison to the "airport" hotel from the same chain (I rented a bicycle).

Comment: Dont booking.com and Agoda offer that already? I mean yeah they don't have that search feature but clicking on "View on Map" does show the nearest stations as well. I always look for those while looking at any property. In fact you can also click on those station names to see which lines run through them.

Comment: @HankyPanky that's a lot of manual work. I want to say "show me the cheapest hotel reachable from the city center in less than 20 minutes by public transport" and have the search engine do the heavy lifting for me. Or "show me every hotel that's reachable from the airport without changing metro lines".

Comment: In cities with good public transport, distance by public transport heavily correlates with distance from city center, since there are no blind spots, etc. This would be more relevant for places with spotty public transit, such as Bay Area.

Comment: In many places “city center” can be a pretty complex or vague concept. Where is the “city center” in Paris? In London? In New York City? In Los Angeles? In Las Vegas?

Comment: @jcaron ideally the website would let me choose what I consider to be be “city center” or just let me sort by public transit distance from an arbitrary address. Booking.com supports this but only for distance as the crow flies.

Comment: @alamar [see this map](https://app.traveltime.com/search/0-lat=51.54182&0-lng=-0.00640&0-title=Westfield%20Stratford%20City%2C%20The%20Street%2C%20Mill%20Meads%2C%20Stratford%20Marsh%2C%20London%20Borough%20of%20Newham%2C%20Greater%20London%2C%20England%2C%20E20%201GN%2C%20United%20Kingdom). If you’re in London, Stradford would be a hidden gem for a hotel reservation as it’s far geographically but seems to have great public transport connectivity. There aren’t many “blind spots” but some spots are faster to get to than others.

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes it does complete sense if a search engine could allow you to rank hotels by walking/driving/public transit time to a given address.

Comment: I know in France some real estate search engines supposedly have this capability, though I haven’t really tested it. Don’t know if any hotel search engines with that feature, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is none giving this hint, you can however try using https://www.mapnificent.net/ or https://app.traveltime.com/ which do provide a time to destination map. You can then find where you should be looking for hotels.

In the past, another website called https://mapumental.com/ did it as well, but it is now closed.

Answer (score 0):

When using Booking.com, type not just the city but the address or place, i.e., "Vienna Central T, Am Hbf, Vienna, Austria" instead of just "Vienna". Then you should be able to sort the results by "Distance to destination".

Comment: Just verified you can do the same on Hotels.com

Comment: That doesn’t give you the distance *by public transit*.