# Is there a way to find hotels along a subway/metro line?

Tags: trains, public-transport, hotels

Is there a way (app or website) to find hotels along a subway or metro line if I don't really care about which station?

For example, if I need to get to Heathrow airport in London, I would like to find a cheap hotel somewhere along the Piccadilly or Elizabeth lines but without searching station by station. Is there a way?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141271/hotel-search-engine-that-sorts-results-by-distance-from-a-given-address-by-publi

Comment: I think you need to narrow this down a little more. For example, the Piccadilly line  has 28 stops from Heathrow just to King's Cross. The cheapest hotels will be furthest away from any "point of interest". i.e. you want to far away both from downtown and the airport.  "Don't really care about which station": seems a bit too broad.

Comment: @Hilmar, OP is not asking which hotel to book but how to find which hotels are near the stops on the lines. Once they know how to find those hotels the search sites allow setting a budget or selecting a chain or whatever other limits they want to apply. I do not think this is too broad at all. The question is aimed at London, and two lines only, but the answers can be useful for other locations as well.

Comment: The question is not restricted to a single city or line(s). It uses London as an example only, and has no other specification except "if I know the line, how do I find hotels on it?". @Willeke

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried a Google search  using

- london hotels near a metro station

and got many surprisingly useful *looking* hits.
Too many to list - here are a few that looked highly apposite.

The search itself [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=london+hotels+near+a+metro+station&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ALiCzsZAfwSfANUwMC5idPkePTIkKkrHYA%3A1672479674728&ei=ugOwY979K5j34-EP4ceCkAE&ved=0ahUKEwjewp-nyKP8AhWY-zgGHeGjABIQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=london+hotels+near+a+metro+station&gs_lcp=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&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)

Hotels near the metro.com ! [here](https://hotelsnearthemetro.com/hotels-near-the-metro-in-london)
You can select within 250 or 500 metres, and choose one of 12 lines, or all lines at once.

[Hotels near London underground](https://www.trivago.com/en-US/opr/hotels-near-london-underground?tc=22&search=500-159354) - Trip advisor.
Each listing shows distance to underground.
Optional map - hover over hotel listing and it shows location on map.

Comment: Nice! [Hotels near the metro.com](https://hotelsnearthemetro.com) answers my question best so far. I am accepting that as the answer. The trip advisor link is nice but it does not say which station/line

Comment: As London doesn't have a "metro" then I'm almost certain 'hotels near a station' might get hits that the word 'metro' might exclude, depending on how smart the algorithm is. 'Tube' might miss overground stations with good central access, too. I live 25 mins from the City, but nowhere near a tube station, I'm on TfL Overground. If you need a specific line, then I'd include that line in the search.

Comment: I was perplexed by "Garglabet" and the link to a closed facebook group didn't help; is that meant to link somewhere publicly accessible?

Comment: @KernelPanic Sorry - my (wry?) joke. Google -> Alphabet -> Garglabet. Maybe Googlabet would be better?

Comment: @KernelPanic Fixed ! :-)  Googlabet <-- Garglabet

Comment: Ah it was more that because the fb group is private and seems unrelated I was wondering if the link itself was miscopied?

Answer (score 7):

This is a variation on [Willeke's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/178496/30703), in that you're not specifically filtering or sorting by proximity to the line, but using the map to do so visually:

- Go to Google Maps
- Search for your destination
- Click on "Hotels" (or type hotels in the search box)
- If public transit lines are not already shown (depends on your Google Maps preferences), hover the "Layers" box (currently bottom left of the map) and click on "Transit".

Now you have both hotels and transit lines (those known to Google maps at least, but at least all London Underground, Overground and the Elizabeth Line are shown) on the same map.

You can zoom and pan around, and you can apply the usual filters on hotels.

Note however that you will have to zoom in quite a bit before you can see the actual stations rather than just the lines (and be aware that **they do not all show up at the same zoom level**).

If you're looking for convenient hotels outside of central London (to reduce costs), note that of course your choice is probably a combination of distance to a station, distance of that station to wherever you intend to go (which affects both time and cost), frequency (for lines which split you probably want to avoid being on a branch with less trains), etc. Remember that it can take over an hour to get from some tube stations to central London, and that tube fares can be pricey.

Also be aware that outside of central London, geographical (as the crow flies) proximity to a tube station does not necessarily mean easy access.

In the case of wanting access to places outside central London (as in the case of Heathrow in your example), then one also needs to pay attention to which branch of the line one considers. Being on the Reading branch of the Elizabeth Line or the Uxbridge branch of the Piccadilly Line will require you to change.

On the Elizabeth Line, this extends to the western branches: services to Heathrow all originate on the Abbey Wood branch, if you are on the Shenfield branch you will have to change trains (though in this case this is extremely easy, one just needs to get off the train in one of the stations in the central section and wait for a train to the right destination on the same platform).

Comment: By "does not necessarily mean easy access" do you mean it might not be easily walkable because of motorways and that sort of thing?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes, or rail yards or other places you can’t easily cross and need to make a detour around. Or even the Thames. A quick glance does not seem to show any such issues along the Piccadilly or Elizabeth lines but it’s always good to be aware of the possibility.

Comment: Er, **Shen**field. Sheffield is in Yorkshire.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey autocorrect strikes again. Fixed.

Comment: Tourists going to Liverpool Lime Street when they want London Liverpool Street are a thing, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using google maps, you can use OpenStreetMap data though the excellent app [OsmAnd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OsmAnd). This allows you to download all the map data and view in offline mode, so before you start your journey you can know for sure that you will have all the map data you need available and no kind of network outage/connection problem are able to ruin your ability to view maps (and bonus there is no tracking involved as well as no cost for data transfers).

Here is a screenshot of around King's Cross with sleeping places POI (point of interest) overlay added:

[image: Screenshot of ormand]

Comment: This helps when actually underway to the hotel, but I think OP wants to know about the hotels near the (underground) rail lines before setting out. Does this method help with that?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an online map or hotel search site and a map of the line if you do not know where it actually runs.

With an online map you may want to search for 'hotels near here' or whatever way they do it on that map, and move your focus along the line.
With hotel sites you can often restrict the budget so you can restrict the results to those you would consider. (More hotels may show up in the map but with a difference in the marker.) I would still zoom in enough that I only have two or three stops worth on the screen and then move the map along if I do not find the hotel I look for.

Comment: I tried that but usually the lines are not shown clearly on those maps so I have to cross reference that with a metro/subway map and that becomes really complicated

Comment: You need a new version of this map (found through a search, I do not even know the site it is on) https://i2-prod.hertfordshiremercury.co.uk/incoming/article4417589.ece/ALTERNATES/s810/0_Tube-map-london-centreJPG.jpg